# Editing a bullet point in beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to highlight the operation of an algorithm using beamer and would need to edit a visualization data structure on a page after each operation. For simplicity, assume that I have a list. The slides would look as follows:

```
---
L: []
---
L: [1]
1. Appended 1 to list
---
L: [1,2]
1. Appended 1 to list
2. Appended 2 to list
---
```

This would be 3 slides in total. I would like L to be positioned in the same location on each slide, so that when I switch to the next slide, something happens to its contents and the corresponding operation performed is added below.

Is there an easy way to get such an effect? I have no absolutely no clue how to provide this effect, but if a minimal template is requested, here it is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{foo}
$L: [1,2]$
\begin{itemize}
\item Appended 1 to list
\item Appended 2 to list
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I'd like to reach this slide through a sequence of 3 slides as explained above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Problems is that I have no clue how to do this. If you want my template: \begin{frame}\end{frame} and fill in the middle what is need to make the slides I want.

Comment: That's a starter point for others such that they do not have to type this of their own...

Answer (score 3):

Use the beamer commands `\only<_range_>{_content_}` or `\onslide<_range_>{_content_}`.
They only show the `_content_` in the supplied `_range_`, e.g. `\only<1>{}` for slide one, `\only<2->{}` for all slides from 2 on etc.

The difference between `only` and `onslide` is the rendering of the output: only acts like the code is only present on this slides, \onslide renders the output but it is just visible on the supplied slides.

In the itemize and enumerate environments you can just use these range-commands after `\item`, no need `for` only or `onslide`.

Here is your example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  L: [\only<1>{ }\only<2->{1}\only<3->{, 2}]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<2-> Appended 1 to list
    \item<3-> Appended 2 to list
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: slide1]
[image: slide2]
[image: slide3]